# How can I convert string to int/Integer if the string contains word?

Tags: java, android, parseint

Basicly I want to convert string word to int like from xml but now from a raw file.
I can do this from xml:

```
final int[] colorArray = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.colors_int);
```

And I have this in the xml file:

```
<integer-array name="colors_int">
            <item>@color/red</item>
            <item>@color/yellow</item>
            <item>@color/blue</item>
   </integer-array>
```

By this I can easily set colors on my objects:

```
view.setBackgroundColor(colorArray[i]);
```

BUT now I have a raw file which contains a colors name dividing them by whitespace: "blue red yellow"

How can I read these into an int array/Integer arraylist, so I can color objects easily?
I tried this:

```
input_file_int.add( Integer.parseInt(line));
```

but it didnt work because the string isnt an int.

```
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "blue"
```

With string arraylist, it works perfectly but I cant use strings to color objects.

How could I do this?

**EDIT:**

I have this example raw file:

```
black
gray
silver
maroon
red
olive
```

My colors.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <!--16 basic color -->
        <color name="black">#000000</color>
        <color name="gray">#808080</color>
        <color name="silver">#C0C0C0</color>
        <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
        <color name="maroon">#800000</color>
    </resources>
```

And thats how I initialized the Integer ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<Integer> input_file_int= new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Comment: String.valueOf(integer) ?

Comment: @Jake `String.valueOf(int)` *converts int to string*, if you want to convert String to int use `Integer.parseInt(string)`

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `Map` of the colors:

```
Map<String, Integer> colors = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
colors.put("blue", 0xff00ff00);

input_file_int.add(colors.get("blue"));
```

EDIT:
If you're trying to do a lookup of the colors listed on your xml, you can do so like so:

```
Resources resources = getResources();
int colorId =  resources.getIdentifier(line, "color", "com.mypackage.myapplication");
int color = resources.getColor(colorId);
input_file_int.add(color);
```

Comment: I have a custom color.xml and I have to fill an int-array / Integer ArrayList from a raw file that I mentioned in the question, these are the restrictions.

Comment: Your original question made it seem like you were just trying to do a mapping.

Comment: Yea, maybe I forgot to mention I have already a custom xml of colors.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Your arraylist
ArrayList<Integer> input_file_int = new ArrayList<Integer>();

// Read raw file
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(getResources().openRawResource(
        R.raw.colors));
try {
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        switch (scanner.next()) {
        // include case of your all 16 (or any number of) colors of your
        // colors.xml file
        case "black":
            input_file_int.add(Integer.parseInt(getResources()
                    .getString(R.color.black).substring(3), 16));
            break;
        case "gray":
            input_file_int.add(Integer.parseInt(getResources()
                    .getString(R.color.gray).substring(3), 16));
            break;
        case "silver":
            input_file_int.add(Integer.parseInt(getResources()
                    .getString(R.color.silver).substring(3), 16));
            break;
        // and keep going on
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(getTitle().toString(), e.getMessage());
} finally {
    scanner.close();
}
// Now, Arraylist contains true Integer value of colors
// Be aware you can't directly use it.
// Use it like this...

view.setBackgroundColor(0xff000000 + input_file_int.get(2));
// Silver in this case
```

Comment: Im using custom color.xml.

Comment: See my edited answer and can you plz show us your custom raw file `colors.xml` and how you've initialized `input_file_int` variable so, we might tell you how you can get **Integer Arraylist**. Thanks

Comment: Ok, so now you can only use `raw file` you cant use `colors.xml` right?

Comment: I can use the colors.xml ! I have to use the raw file ONLY for coloring the objects on the actual level of the app. So I will have more raw files - every file represents the set of colors of the current level. So I have to fill an array by the raw file then color the objects - but the coloring is okay after I have the int array because I can color the objects by an int array, I know that already. I used integer-array in xml file, I could easily gather the infos from that as I mentioned in the question ( view.setBackgroundColor(colorArray[i]); -> where colorArray is an int array.

Comment: See edited answer, and Don't forget to change compiler to 1.7 from Project-->Properties-->Java Compiler->JDK Compliance. Enjoy!

Comment: In your situation, there's no other way

Comment: By this method if I have 10levels of 16colors, I have to make 160 switchcases?